# How to use FactoryBot with a read-only database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have 2 Rails applications. The first one manages user data. The second one has read only access to the first's database to retrieve that user data.

```
user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
# Test user associations that only exist in the 2nd application
```

Obviously that line will fail as the user cannot be created due to database-level permissions. My first thought would be to open up the first database's `_test` database to have full write permissions, but this feels wrong as it would have different permissions than the production environment, potentially hiding/causing other issues.

**What is the best approach for using FactoryBot to test aspects of the second application using mock user data from the first?**

**Update**

One thought I had was to pre-load a dummy test database with data and ensure the 2nd application has read only access to it. Then my tests would simply query for an existing user (would need to have prior knowledge about the data inside though) instead of using FactoryBot to create ones. Is this a viable approach?

Comment: "Is this a viable approach" - yes. It's called fixtures and it is what people do in "vanilla" rails, without factory_bot.

Comment: Can you explain how fixtures would help? I may have a misunderstanding of them. The database is read-only for the 2nd application. Wouldn't the fixture fail to be applied?

Comment: I meant the general idea: some seed data exists before tests are run. And tests are assuming structure/content of that pre-existing data ("user with id=123 and name=Joe is expected to exist", etc.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. The only downside at this point is that the fixture data would be loaded externally. When using fixtures normally, you can easily see what data lives in the database and it can be controlled/modified/etc. This read-only thing is throwing a wrench into plans, haha

Comment: Yeah, it is, it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Loading a fixture would be a good choice here as you can simulate the read only database with your user data interactions.

You will need to read in a yml or xml file similar setup to your db .. parse out the mappings of the file and then you can use it.

Quick example:

```
def fixture_file_path(filename)
  Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/#{filename}").to_s
end

def read_fixture_file(filename)
  File.read fixture_file_path(filename)
end

let(:fixture)      { read_fixture_file("file.xml") }
```

Then create a subject here which will be useful as you will be calling this in many tests .. call the fixture

```
subject(:service) { described_class.call fixture }
```

Then you can go from there and build the interactivity to test how you need.